# OnclickListener in a checkbox (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, checkbox, onclicklistener

here is part of my code which includes the CheckBox(ChckBoxNo):

```
    final CheckBox ChckBoxNo = (CheckBox)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.ChkBoxNo);

                                  ChckBoxNo.setChecked(true);

                                   ChckBoxNo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                           if (ChckBoxNo.isChecked()) {

                                         ChckBoxNo.setChecked(false);
                                           }
                                           else if (!ChckBoxNo.isChecked())
                                           {
                                               ChckBoxNo.setChecked(true);
                                           }
                                       }
                                   });
```

At the begining I set true for the isChecked() method on my checkbox , then I implement the onclicklistener on the checkbox.
When I run the app the checkbox is Checked as I defined eralier , but when I click on the checkbox ,It's unchecked and then immidately checked again(I didnt clciked again on the checkbox! )
What should I do in order to fix that,what wrong in my code ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

try this:

```
checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            checkBox.setChecked(checkPasswordExist());
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                        // your code to checked checkbox                        
                        }
                    } else {
                        // your code to  no checked checkbox
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 4):

A `Checkbox` will handle the "checking" process automatically - you do not have to manage this yourself for the standard usage.

Check out [this example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html) from the docs. Here, when a click event is caught, they are doing operations based on the `isChecked()` state.

Answer (score 1):

You're battling the CheckBox. It's standart behavior that checkbox change states, you dont need to do that by yourself.

Remove setChecked true and false and paste something usefull there instead )

Comment: And if you just want to know when the state changes, set an OnCheckChangedListener instead.

Comment: *thats lead me to another question* : this should be a hint that you need to  investigate and create that other question, this is not a forum

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to set the checked state on the same that you have klicked.

You shold handle some other Operations on specific state.